# Ember.run.bind is not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, bind, ember-cli

I am trying to get ember.run.bind to work but it just doesn't seem to work, any idea? I have tried all combinations

```
_didInsertElement: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function () {
    Ember.run.bind(this, this.doSomething);
  })
```

or

```
_didInsertElement: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function () {
    Ember.run.bind(this, function() {
      this.doSomething();
    });
  })
```

or

```
_didInsertElement: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function () {
    var _this = this;
    Ember.run.bind(this, function() {
      _this.doSomething();
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ember.run.bind()` returns a function that you can then call.  It's meant for some asynchronous execution, so it doesn't expect to be called immediately, in the case of calling it immediately, it's unlikely you would need to use bind.

```
var func = Ember.run.bind(this, this.doSomething);

func();
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/diqelezika/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Ha I should have tried this but I felt this could not be it, thanks a bunch